# Sorting custom array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array.

```
let test_array = [[98,6,54,32],[10,20,30,40]];
```

I create another array

`var test = [[],[]];`

I would like to sort the new array from the smallest to the largest value and I would like the second one to follow this order in order to return this.
`test[0] = [6,32,54,98];`
`test[1] = [20,40,30,10];`

I only managed to do this
`test_confronto[0]  = test_array[0].sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });`

I don't know how to continue.

Thank you.

Comment: you should specify what you mean by smallest and largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "zip" them together:

```js
const zipped = test_array[0].map((_, idx) =>
  test_array.map((subarray) => subarray[idx]),
)
```

Then sort `zipped` array:

```js
zipped.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
```

And finally "unzip" it:

```js
const result = zipped[0].map((_, idx) =>
  zipped.map((subarray) => subarray[idx]),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.sort` as well and `indexOf`

```js
let test_array = [[98,6,54,32],[10,20,30,40]];
const sortArray = [20,40,30,10];
let test = [[],[]];
test[0]  = test_array[0].sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
test[1] = test_array[1].sort((a, b) => sortArray.indexOf(a) - sortArray.indexOf(b));
console.log(test)
```

Comment: Poor time complexity, will fail if duplicates are present.

Comment: @Luatic what do you mean? if there are any duplicates, it will still sort them out right next to each other in the same order as the `sortArray` if this is my array `[10,20,30,40,40,30,20]` the result will be `[20, 20, 40, 40, 30, 30, 10]`

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it handles duplicates fine. If you want good performance, consider building a map from numbers to indices.

Comment: How would you do it with `map`?

Comment: Not `map`, `Map`, as in `const indices = new Map(); sortArray.forEach((elem, i) => ndices.set(elem, i));`, which allows you to replace the O(n) `sortArray.indexOf` with an expected O(1) `indices.get`.